# Cocoapods : target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries when installing 'VialerSIPLib'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, pjsip

I'm trying to install an objective-c Wrapper for Jsip 'VialerSIPLib' and use it in my swift project here is my pod

```
platform :ios, ’10.0’

use_frameworks!
target 'EMedicalAdmin' do
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.1'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3'
pod 'SwiftyAvatar', '~> 1.0'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'
pod 'Eureka', '~> 2.0.0-beta.1'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController.git', :branch => 'develop'
pod 'PKHUD', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.1.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod "FlexibleSteppedProgressBar"
pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu.git', :branch => 'swift-3.0'
pod 'VialerSIPLib'
end
```

but i get this error when installing :-

> target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries:

and if i remove

> use_frameworks!

from my podfile it would work but all my other swift based pods won't work

so, i'm left with using only this one pod (VialerSIPLib) or Use all my other pods except it

Comment: [the documentation for this pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/VialerSIPLib) says it depends on `Vialer-pjsip-iOS`, `CocoaLumberjack` and `Reachability`.  Do things get better for you when you add those three pods to your Podfile?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann they already get installed automatically when i install the 'VialerSIBLib'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please add this to your podspec: `s.static_framework = true`
This is available from cocoapods version 1.4.0.

It worked for me.!!

Comment: @PranavGupta: Can you please show me the code like where you put the `podspec: s.static_framework = true`. Sorry for the silly question, I am new to Cocoapods. Thank you

Comment: @LuongTruong the only line you need to paste is 
"s.static_framework = true" 

Please dont forget to use this line at the top of the podspec file 
"Pod::Spec.new do |s|"

Comment: @PranavGupta: Thank you for your comment, I found it :)

Comment: @LuongTruong Where is it? I saw your question and did not get any clue. How can I edit a pod's podspec?

Comment: @Faruk: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212049/ios-where-to-put-s-static-framework-true. Hope it help

Comment: @LuongTruong yeah, that is thread I got here. However I could not find any .podspec for the pod I am trying to install. Can you explain the how did you locate it?

Comment: @Faruk we cant access the podspec file of someone else's pod. It is not available with the Pod. Only the creator of framework or pod can access it.

Comment: @Faruk: I am working in a React Native project, I found the podspec file in node_modules/<lib name>/ios

Comment: Are there any bad implications that adding `s.static_framework` can have?

Answer (score 2):

`use_frameworks!` should be enough but sometimes the pod.lock file gets corrupted.

So you can delete the pod.lock file and then do 
`pod repo update` and `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

if any one is Still wondring ,it can't be Done

> Using dynamic vendored frameworks shouldn't be a problem even if the
>   developer isn't using CocoaPods with use_frameworks!, unless they for
>   some reason need a static lib, such as if building a command line
>   tool, where static linking is preferable.

So .You Could add the static library manually and link it in you project or wait for the vendor to Change the library into a dynamic Framework

More info [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3729)

For me this is how i solved it :-

1- Downloaded the static library using Cocoapods without use_frameworks!

2- used Carthage for Adding other libraries

3- and if a library Doesn't have a Carthage support i would do it manually (Not advised since alot of Duplicate dependencies may Appear)

Answer (score 1):

I put up a repo to show how to do: https://github.com/Lucashuang0802/CocoaPodsWithCarthage

There are a couple things to do:
- install your objective-c lib via CocoaPods without indicating `use_framework!` in the Podfile
- install your pure Swift module via Carthage

You should be able to compile fine with this solution.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

It's a weird one.
For me uninstalling and installing again worked.
Steps -

1. Comment(#) the error causing pod in pod file
2. Pod install
3. Uncomment the line in pod file and save
4. Pod install