# ios - where to put s.static_framework = true

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am level 0 in CocoaPods. When I am using the `pod install` there is an error says:

```
The 'Pods-App' target has transitive dependencies that include static frameworks
```

I try to search around and see [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236176/cocoapods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-when?rq=1) in the FIRST answer.

Pranav Gupta said that I need to add `s.static_framework = true` to my podspec. However, I don't know exactly where.

Please guide me if you know how I can put the `s.static_framework = true` in my Podfile.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `s.static_framework` is an option for library creators to add to the podspec. It is not an option for library consumers in the Podfile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

thank you for helping, I am able to find out the solution. Below is the solution, hope it can help other people like me.

I am using Pod to integrate the Firebase to my React native app `(@react-native-firebase/app)` but receive this error:

[image]

We have to add `s.static_framework = true` in the Podfile of react-native-firebase, NOT Pod file of our project.

The Pod file of react-naive-firebase named `RNFApp.podspecs`. After we open it, we can see there is a line

```
s.static_framework = false
```

Just change it from `false` to `true`

Hope my answer can help.

Comment: Or better use config: https://rnfirebase.io/#allow-ios-static-frameworks

Comment: @KeshaAntonov this is it. Thanks.

Comment: It should be: "just change it from ```false``` to ```true``` "

Comment: Hi can anyone tell here where i can find podspecs file of my framework(to be installed) specially under which folder path??

Answer (score 1):

If your base `podspec_A` is `s.static_framework = true` then some other `podspec` integrates `podspec_A`; this `podspec` also needs to set `s.static_framework = true`, otherwise it will cause the `Pods-YourProject` target to have transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (your podspec).

Answer (score 0):

Add `$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true` to the top of Podfile as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks)

Answer (score -1):

For pod install command, where error is "target has transitive dependencies that include static frameworks" basically means there are static frameworks attached with pod & in swift pod file you have to comment user_framework line as it stop the use of static frameworks.

So for this kind of error please comment use_frameworks! line in pod file.

Thanks,
Ratneshwar

Comment: Comment `use_frameworks!` and add `use_modular_headers!`